# Firefox consuming 100% CPU; about:performance shows nothing

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox 88, Ubuntu 20.04.

Firefox randomly starts using 100% CPU. This persists even if I close/suspend all tabs.

I looked at about:performance and the extensions/open tabs all have low/zero "Enery Impact", which afaik is a proxy to CPU usage.

This situation persists until I restart Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Try `about:processes`

Comment: Getting the same thing on Firefox (latest, not ESR) on Debian testing, problem has persisted for a couple weeks now.

Comment: `about:processes` shows "Firefox" itself using 1GB Memory and 110% CPU.

Every other process (about 20 showing) at under 100MB and well under 1% of CPU.